# how to use async await nodejs function

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2

I am trying to create my customers shopping cart using a unique session id generated when the customers add something to their cart. The problem is, it is inserting into the cart before creating the table (cart). I feel this is an async await thing, can someone help?

```
    app.post('/addtocart', (req, res) => {

    createCartTable (req, res)

    var user = "insert into " + req.session.sessionID + " (NAME, PRICE, QUANTITY, IMAGE_URL, PRODUCTID) VALUES ('" + req.body.name + "', '" + req.body.price + "', '" + req.body.quantity + "', '" + req.body.image_url + "', '" + req.body.productid + "')";
    ibmdb.open(db2ConnString, function(err, conn) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        conn.query(user, function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            selectcart(req, res)
            // res.render("catalogue", {
            //     page_title: "catalogue",
            //     data: rows,
            // })

            conn.close(function() {
            });
        });
    });
})
```

the `createCartTable (req, res)` function doesn't get called until after the insert query is done. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create put that insert query into its own function, where I then called it from within the create table function... Workaround to the async stuff, probably not the right way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Is createCartTable an asynchronous function? That is to say, when it's defined elsewhere, is it defined as `async createCartTable(){...}`?

**The following assumes that it is:**
Yes, this is an async-await problem. Since `createCartTable()` is asynchronous, everything else following it is allowed to execute while `createCartTable()` finishes resolving/rejecting its promise. All you should need to do is change `createCartTable()` to `await createCartTable()`. The await keyword tells the program to stop code execution until that function has fulfilled its promise.

If you'd like extra context on async/await & promises, you can check out some of the following links, or just ask. Sometimes the mozilla docs are a little rough.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Edit: I saw your own comment- that actually was just the way you had to do things pre- async/await! It works just fine that way if you want to keep it, async/await is essentially just syntactic sugar for promises & asynchronous stuff, makes things easier to read & comprehend.